# Button to call one function upon being pressed down and to call another when released?

Tags: ios, xcode, touch, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I have a view containing three buttons.

one button starts audio being recorded, the other button stops the audio being recorded and the third button plays the recorded audio.

I want to condense the record start and stop into one button so that when pressed it records but then when released it stops recording.

I tried doing this by using two events on one button with touch down to start the recording and then touch up inside to stop it, however it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a UIButton, you should create a view and style it to look like the button you want.

Then rely on the touches began & ended methods to provide the functionality you want.

In this particular case, I create a custom view class that you can use.

The following code is for Swift 3.0:

```
class TouchView : UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        // Start recording
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        // End recording
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIButton to which you have attached a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer). You get a `.began` message when the recognizer decides that the user is holding a finger down on the view, and an `.ended` message when the finger is lifted. Set the button's `isSelected` to indicate the "down" state:

```
@IBAction func doPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        (sender.view as! UIControl).isSelected = true
        // start recording
    case .ended:
        (sender.view as! UIControl).isSelected = false
        // stop recording
    default: break
    }
}
```